# Trying to understand this statement in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I came across the following statement in Python:

```
a = m[:,1].a - m[:,0].a
```

If I remove the `.a` parts, I understand that we are trying to subtract the first column in the array from the second column.

What does adding `.a` do?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what `m` looks like?

Comment: `.a` is accessing that attribute on whatever is returned by `m[:,1]` I can only assume it is some `object` dtype.

Comment: No, you're subtracting the values of the `a` attributes from whatever the slices are returning.

Comment: Does slicing allow comma in syntax.... Not that familiar with python

Comment: @Naidu technically, it passes a *tuple* of slices to `my_obj.__getitem__`, you can implement `__getitem__` to accept whatever you want. The `numpy.ndarray` objects allow tuples of slices to do multi-dimensional slicing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Naidu you can check with a plain dict yourself (not with a slice, though b/c unhashable): `a = {}; a[1, 2] = 0; a.keys()`

Comment: use `print(m[:,1].a)` to see what `m[:,1].a` is.

Comment: Where do you find this code? I see from other questions that you are doing image work.  Is this part of some module.  The indexing looks like `numpy`, but the `.a` attribute or property doesn't look right - unless it is a `recarray`.

Answer (score 0):

When writing my comment I realized that this notation is consistent with a `recarray`.

Define a dtype with a couple of fields

```
In [28]: dt = np.dtype([('a',int),('b',float)])
```

Initialize a `recarray` with this `dtype`:

```
In [29]: arr = np.ones((3,2), dtype=dt).view(np.recarray)
In [30]: arr['a'] = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
In [31]: arr
Out[31]: 
rec.array([[(0,  1.), (1,  1.)],
           [(2,  1.), (3,  1.)],
           [(4,  1.), (5,  1.)]], 
          dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<f8')])
In [32]: arr.a
Out[32]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

The first field can be accessed with `arr['a']` or `arr.a` (structured array or recarray attribute).  Now we can write an expression like yours:

```
In [34]: arr[:,0].a - arr[:,1].a
Out[34]: array([-1, -1, -1])
```

Structured arrays are common on SO, especially when loading data from a CSV file.  The recarray variant may actually be older, but has fallen out of use.  For example, the `recfunctions` library requires a special import.  Apparently the attribute notation isn't that special or useful.

If this isn't right, you need to tell us more about the source of the quote.